# Change prefab color from script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a smoke prefab that I need to change the color from script since the color will be change during playtime.

I am instantiating the prefab and attempting to change color to red like this:

```
class Smoke1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject myPrefab;
    public GameObject canvasObject;

void Start()
    {
        GameObject newSmoke = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(397, -394, 90), Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        newSmoke.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
        newSmoke.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        newSmoke.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color",Color.red);
    }
```

As you can see in the picture, the prefab as a material but the script is not changing the color at all (black in the picture):
[image]

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I just noticed the error about the missing mesh renderer, how can I add it to a prefab that is instantiated by script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the start color of the `ParticleSystem`, not the material of an nonexistent `MeshRenderer`.

```
   newSmoke.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().startColor = Color.red ;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-startColor.html